# How do I programmatically implement account lockout after 5 invalid login attempts?

Tags: 8

I created a custom login form. I created a module for this, then a controller to show the form and login the user. I used the function `user_login_finalize($user);` to login the user.

So the question is, if the user entered an invalid password, how do I implement account lockout after 5 invalid login attempts?

I'm using Drupal 8.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Isn't that already in Drupal core? See how [UserLoginForm](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/8.4.x) uses the Flood service. Look for the comment "Default is to allow 5 failed attempts every 6 hours."

Comment: @marcvangend, I created a custom login, I didn't use the drupal default login. Yes I know it has something to do with the Flood service, what i'm asking is how do I implement the account lockout programmatically?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Unfortunately I don't have instructions for you. Hopefully reading the code of UserLoginForm can teach you how the Flood service is used. [FloodInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Flood%21FloodInterface.php/interface/FloodInterface/8.4.x) seems pretty well documented.